# Redhat Yum install issue zlib_1.2.2

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel

I have libz 1.2.3 installed but this package seems to only want 1.2.2 but I can't find any repro that hs it. Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

```
Error: Package: erlang-erts-R14B-04.3.el6.x86_64 (epel)            
Requires: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.2)(64bit)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the 
problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me:

`wget
https://elearning.erlang-solutions.com/couchdb//rbingen_adapter//package_R16B_centos664_1361907767/esl-erlang-R16B-2.x86_64.rpm
yum install esl-erlang-R16B-2.x86_64.rpm
wget
https://github.com/jasonmcintosh/esl-erlang-compat/blob/master/rpmbuild/RPMS/noarch/esl-erlang-compat-R14B-1.el6.noarch.rpm?raw=true
yum install esl-erlang-compat-R14B-1.el6.noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
yum --allow-downgrade install zlib-1.2.2
```

Comment: I think the problem will still exist that the 1.2.2 package isn't available....
`No package install available.
No package zlib-1.2.2 available.
Nothing to do`

Comment: `Setting up Downgrade Process
No package install available.
Only Upgrade available on package: zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64
Nothing to do`

Comment: well it seams that 1.2.2 is VERY out dated .... was used in rhel 4. 
So it seams you have a copple options ...

1. You could see if there was an updated package of erlang that you could use. (best bet)

2. you could compile and build the version of zlib that you need

3. you could sim link libz.so.1.2.2 to libz.so (could possibly break thinks)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but "Alternatively: adding the repository entry manually" of this page worked like a champ:

https://www.erlang-solutions.com/downloads/download-erlang-otp

Basically,

RPM packages are signed. To add Erlang Solutions key, execute command:

```
rpm --import http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/erlang_solutions.asc
```

Add the following lines to some file in /etc/yum.repos.d/:

```
[erlang-solutions]  
name=Centos $releasever - $basearch - Erlang Solutions 
baseurl=http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/centos/$releasever/$basearch  
gpgcheck=1 
gpgkey=http://packages.erlang-solutions.com/rpm/erlang_solutions.asc 
enabled=1
```

Make sure to $releasever and $basearch to match your system.